# iphone application update

Tags: iphone, xcode

i would like to check:

if a user downloaded my app, than i make some update to app, data etc., itunes will auto remind the user of the update through app store, and the user can update for free? or do i have to set such reminder in my application?

else, is there a way for me to send this notification?

thks

Rgds

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the phone notifies of app updates through the App Store app and app updates are free.

Alternatively, you can use [push notifications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to notify the user that a new version is available, or display an alert the next time they open the app.

To do the latter you can query the version of the app (`[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];`) and compare it to a value provided by your web server.

Comment: do i need to code the notification for app store?

alternatively how do i notify user new version is available?

Comment: so the update will be free to user who has already downloaded the app?
the notification part(tableview) have some images/text etc. i don't have to set it? thks